# Telnetlib's read_until in Python will not read expected string. What are Alternatives?

Tags: python, timeout, telnet, telnetlib

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

host = "10.28.103.126"
user = b"apc"
password = b"apc"
outlet = b"8"

tnObject = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
print("yes")
tnObject.read_until(b"User Name :")
tnObject.write(user + b"\n")
print("sent user")
tnObject.read_until(b" ")
tnObject.write(password + b"\n")
print("sent password")
tnObject.read_until(b"Name ")
tnObject.write(b"1" + b"\n")
print("sent first command")
tnObject.read_until(b">")
tnObject.write(outlet + b"\n")
print("sent second command")
tnObject.read_until(b">")
tnObject.write(b"1" + b"\n")
print("sent third command")
tnObject.read_until(b">")
tnObject.write(b"2" + b"\n") #(1 is ON) (2 is OFF)
print("sent fourth command")
tnObject.read_until(b"Enter ")
tnObject.write(b"yes" + b"\n" + b"\n")
tnObject.read_until(b">")
tnObject.close()

print(tnObject.read_all())
```

I've tried dozens of different string combinations that should be read, I've tried adding spaces before and after, spelling, and simple b" " to expect a space but nothing seems to work to send the first command.  The other 3 strings prior were read just fine.  What is an alternative to this read_until?

Also, I've tried sleep(.5) and sleep(1) but that didn't work either.  I've also tried to just write strings into the buffer without waiting for the read_until. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to look at this thread? [Python - telnet - automation APC PDU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306410/python-telnet-automation-apc-pdu) - the way that this issue was fixed was to add "\r\n" when you write the username and the password.
So you need to use:
    tnObject.read_until(b"User Name :")
    tnObject.write(user + b"\r\n")
    tnObject.read_until(b" ")
    tnObject.write(password + b"\r\n")

No need to use the tnObject.read_until(b">")

Note that for the other commands, you can leave the "\n" at the end:
    tnObject.write(b"userList\n") should work fine

I tried that on my APC system and it worked.

Hope it will work for you too!